# Openlayers 3 map initially only draws on window resize

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a popup window that comes up when you click on a map marker.  Within the popup window there is a minimap that shows the point that was clicked on, but zoomed in, so a thumbnail of that point on the ground.  This minimap is an innerHTML element in the popup window.  When I first click on the marker, this map element is blank, but when I resize my browser window the map appears.  Also when I click on a different marker, the map will appear if I don't close the popup.  The map just does not show up when the popup initially appears unless I resize the browser.  Does anyone know what could be the issue?  Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to know without see some code.

Answer (score 8):

I've had this issue in the past - on window resizes.  I tend to trigger a resize to force it when starting.

Try calling `map.getMap().updateSize();` after you setup the map in the popup?

Comment: Although this works it seems like a really silly hack. I only have this problem in Chrome browsers but not in FireFox for some reason.

Comment: This is still useful for OpenLayers 6. Though in my code it's just `map.updateSize()`. Thank you.